# dir(element) returns non-existing element. Trying to use getattr(element, ...) fails

Tags: python, lxml.objectify

Basically what i do is:

```
attrs = dir(oe)
for attr in attrs:
  attr_obj = getattr(oe, attr)

  .... more code ...
```

but the `getattr` call fails with: `AttributeError: no such child: comment`

`oe` is an `ObjectifiedElement` of the `lxml.objectify` library.

When i look into `oe` with PyCharm it shows the `comment` attribute but also fails to resolve it.

What is going on here? How can this attribute be shown by `dir` when it does not exist?

Comment: I do not see the `comment` attribute in my lxml version's `ObjectifiedElement` . Can you show an [MCVE] that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @AnandSKumar No i cannot, as the code that does this is merging various xml files together and i guess it some point a comment gets inserted and then removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert but lxml maybe redefining `__getattr__` . From their source code:

```
def __getattr__(self, tag):
    u"""Return the (first) child with the given tag name.  If no namespace
    is provided, the child will be looked up in the same one as self.
    """
    if is_special_method(tag):
        return object.__getattr__(self, tag)
    return _lookupChildOrRaise(self, tag)
```

see https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/lxml.objectify.pyx

Moreover, about the `dir` method, you have:

dir([object])
Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

If the object has a method named **dir**(), this method will be called and must return the list of attributes. This allows objects that implement a custom **getattr**() or **getattribute**() function to customize the way dir() reports their attributes.

If the object does not provide **dir**(), the function tries its best to gather information from the object’s **dict** attribute, if defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not necessarily complete, and may be inaccurate when the object has a custom **getattr**().

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

Comment: Yeah i guess this is the root of the problem. `ObjectifiedElement` overrides `__dict__` with a different method then it uses to look up things in `__getattr__`.